# How to bring Wear OS OnGoingActivity back to front from a service

Tags: android, wear-os

The Wear OS application is designed to display messages at random intervals while active. To achieve this, the application utilizes a background service paired with a notification linked to an ongoing activity.

- Launch the activity.
- Click to enable the "active" state, establishing a connection to a service, finish() the activity
- Form the service, build an ongoing activity tied to a notification.
- Display the notification as an ongoing activity on the Wear OS home screen, confirming the application's continuous operation.
- After a specified delay, bring the activity to the foreground to display a message.

> When a click occurs on notification icon or in recent app the activity is bring to front.

I would like to do the same from a postDelayed handler in the service so i try this :

```kotlin
    handler.postDelayed({
            Log.d(TAG, "Post delayed fired")
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
            val pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
            pIntent.send()
        }, delayMillis)
```

this cause this log:

```
2024-01-23 11:18:14.220   540-4470  ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       I  START u0 {flg=0x20000 cmp=com.pixtogram.wear.posipulse/.presentation.MainActivity} from uid 10088
2024-01-23 11:18:14.222   540-4470  ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       W  Background activity start [callingPackage: com.pixtogram.wear.posipulse; callingUid: 10088; appSwitchState: 2; isCallingUidForeground: false; callingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; callingUidProcState: FOREGROUND_SERVICE; isCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; realCallingUid: 10088; isRealCallingUidForeground: false; realCallingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; realCallingUidProcState: FOREGROUND_SERVICE; isRealCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; originatingPendingIntent: PendingIntentRecord{48f29d com.pixtogram.wear.posipulse startActivity (allowlist: b7bf5d9:+30s0ms/0/NOTIFICATION_SERVICE/NotificationManagerService)}; allowBackgroundActivityStart: false; intent: Intent { flg=0x20000 cmp=com.pixtogram.wear.posipulse/.presentation.MainActivity }; callerApp: ProcessRecord{752085a 13164:com.pixtogram.wear.posipulse/u0a88}; inVisibleTask: false]
2024-01-23 11:18:14.227   540-4470  ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       W  startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { flg=0x20000 cmp=com.pixtogram.wear.posipulse/.presentation.MainActivity }
```

When a click on notification logs this:

```
2024-01-23 11:20:50.119   540-4470  ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       I  START u0 {flg=0x20000 cmp=com.pixtogram.wear.posipulse/.presentation.MainActivity} from uid 10088
2024-01-23 11:20:50.123   540-4470  ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       W  startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { flg=0x20000 cmp=com.pixtogram.wear.posipulse/.presentation.MainActivity }
```

I'm not able to understand why the activity is launch in background in that case, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the log statements, you need to set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag on your intent when launching an Activity from a Service (and any other context that is not an Activity context in itself).

Try building your Intent and PendingIntent like this:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

val pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
```